# How to start a checkers game session with ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, websocket

Sending moves with ajax makes sense to me. But how does a game session even get started? How does one player send an offer to play to another player? And once the second player accepts how does the first player receive the offer? I know about WebSockets for allowing pushing of data. But how have games in the past made this work without WebSockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with simple ajax requests, thus you need some server to manage all game sessions.
You just need to create some function which sends request to server every x seconds and checks if the user accepted the game request.

```
var listener = setInterval(listen,1000);

function listen() {
  //your ajax request to server to check if user2 acccepted the request
}
```

When the game accepted you can simply stop the listener from working

```
clearInterval(listener);
```